# Instantiate new class from class instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

In php we can do this:

```
$classInstance = new MyClass();
$className = get_class_name($classInstance);
$newInstance = new $className;
```

How can I do the same in javascript?

I tried with `Object.creat` and `Object.assign`, however when calling methods from the new class, the old was was still being referenced:

```
  const newInstance = Object.assign(
    Object.create(
      Object.getPrototypeOf(oldInstace)
    ),
    oldInstance
  );

  newInstance.method(); // "this" still referencing oldInstance
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is not a duplicate of that question. That question does not cover how to instantiate an object. It would be a useful question to link to in an answer though.

Comment: @Omn It looks like it to me. `new foo.constructor()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance that would be the correct answer, but I do not see that clearly explained anywhere. While the answer to this question may well be understood by carefully reading that page, none of those answers apply directly to this question.

Comment: It would be the correct answer with the proviso that you can't use it from the constructor as so:  

var foo = null;
class Bar {
... constructor() {
..... foo = new this.constructor();
..... }
... }
> baz = new Bar();
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Note that foo is definitely in scope here so had we done this from another method we should have correctly gotten another instance of the class.